# Why does this character continue to tell the same story?

Tags: interstellar

After landing on Dr. Mann's Planet, the crew discusses Mann's findings. Mann explains that he found evidence of a safe atmosphere further below on the planet.

I understand why

> [Mann attempted to kill Cooper](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/why-did-mann-attempt-to-kill-cooper-in-interstellar),

but I don't understand

> why he continued to lie to the crew at all. It makes sense that he lied to get a crew to come down and rescue him, but there was no real reason to propagate false hope instead of just admitting to the ruse. Did he think that they would just leave him there stranded knowing that the planet was not a fit?

Comment: Because he's a nutter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's important to remember that Mann is not thinking rationally. He has been broken by the psychological pressure of his extreme isolation.

In the case of prisoners in [solitary confinement](http://www.apa.org/monitor/2012/10/solitary.aspx):

> Many inmates experience panic attacks, depression and paranoia, and some suffer hallucinations

Mann has been far more isolated than any prisoner. So it is plausible that he has slipped into paranoia and delusions. It is quite likely that

> he *does* think the other astronauts will leave him stranded or even kill him because of his deception.

Alternatively, Mann may simply fear that

> if he returns to Earth with the others, he will be severely punished for causing the mission to fail. After all, by diverting the *Endurance* to a non-viable world, he may have effectively doomed the human race to extinction. At the very least, Mann would become known as one of the most evil criminals in history; he might be executed or even subjected to torture.

From this point of view, it is rational (albeit extremely selfish) for Mann to maintain his story. Assuming that

> he leaves the other astronauts behind and returns to Earth

he can make up whatever story he wants.

Comment: I've only seen it once so far, but as I recall, Mann wasn't trying to get back to earth—he was trying to complete the mission

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: I don't think that was settled either way. Even if they went with Plan B and founded a new colony, similar considerations apply. If Mann was accompanied by others, he would go down in history/mythology as the coward who almost doomed humanity; if he was alone, the colonists he raised from freeze-dried embryos would know him as the man who single-handedly saved the human race. That is plenty of motivation to abandon his comrades.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit After a few generations he might even be remembered as some sort of god.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple.

Mann needed the lie to be maintained long enough for all the material to be shipped down from Endurance.    Otherwise the landing crew could just pick up and leave and go to the next planet.

He wanted to get back to Earth, not just have the company of a handful of individuals.

If he destroyed enough material to make the mission a failure, there would have no choice but to return to Earth.

Comment: I think Mann preferred to complete the mission, just not on his failed planet.

Answer (score 1):

You say you understand why

> he would want to kill Coop,

and this is the answer to your question.

> Without the false promise, how else would Mann isolate Coop to make his attack?

And so,

> while Mann is clearly mad (as evidenced especially by his behavior leading up to his demise in the airlock), I feel like his lie about the planet is fairly logical given his desire to complete the real mission (of which, if you'll remember, Plan A was never really part).

Comment: Even if his goal is to just go on and complete Plan B, there's no need to tell them that the planet they were on was habitable. I get that the attempt to kill the crew was to cover up the lie - I just don't totally understand why he felt the need to continue lying in the first place. The best anyone can come up with was that he was crazy, which may be all it is.

Comment: I don't think his attempt to kill the one person in particular was about covering up the lie—I think it was about removing the one person who was committed to returning to Earth.

Comment: Well, he destroyed the habitat with Romilly in it as well.

Comment: If memory serves me, he did that after his plans with Coop didn't go as smoothly as he might have liked. Memory may not serve me, though, and he could just be a straight up cuckoo and not worthy of my defense :-)

Comment: I understood it that it was actually a booby-trap within the robot (I forget its name, but Mann's version of TARS/CASE) that was set to destroy upon tampering. I may have misunderstood though.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I had forgotten about that. Very good evidence that he planned to wipe out/steal a ship from whoever came to get him.

Answer (score 0):

I think none of the answers so far answer that.

First - no, Mann is not that mad yet that he would have wanted to get back to Earth. Mann tries to take command of the ship -because- Cooper decides to go home, to prevent that and to execute plan B instead.

Second - no, Mann did not want to wait to get the cargo down, he tried to postpone that ("we should wait"), getting camp and colony cargo down was pressured by Cooper who wanted to start his journey home.

Third - why continuing the deception at all after the crew landed? The Lazarus missions were missions of the "bravest humans in history", those that landed on a world that showed no promise were supposed to stay silent ("hence the bravery") which means accepting that they will not be rescued - accepting their own death. Mann was, when the missions started, known as the "remarkable one", the one who managed to convince the people to follow him, he was the head of the entire mission project until he landed on the planet. Now this "remarkable" person shows not being able to resist the urge to press the button (for thumbs up pinging). An incredible failure, incredible weakness in all eyes that would discover that - his plan was to keep that hidden. What he was planning was to convince them that the data were real (breathable atmosphere on the surface) but actually too instable (he starts talking about those areas not being stable, you can see where he's getting at). So that the entire crew (now including Mann with his still "remarkable" reputation) could start to planet Edmunds. 
Cooper, when pressing to let him get back to Earth, presing to hurry up with the cargo and finally wanting to go down to one of the breathable spots to start setting up the camp so that he can leave - makes it unevoidable and necessary for Mann to kill him.

Mann lost his bravery (or maybe, without knowing it, never had it) when he faked the data and pinged his thumbs up (and - in the movie's vocabulary - showed the evil that he brought with him). But he did -not- lose his mind. Trying to steal the Endurance, the entire docking sequence were an act of utter panic and final despair when he realised that Cooper survived as now both his deception was uncovered and Cooper will still want to get back to Earth instead of executing plan B. This was not irrational from Mann's perspective or mad - just "evil" (and techinally messed up as this was not his domain).